# Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) : negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values

Tags: r, glm, glmmtmb, tmb

I have some data on *Drosophila* developmental time. I'm running it against treatment with vial specified as a random effect, as described below:

```r
model_tddVZ <- glmmTMB(age ~ treatment + (1|vial), tddcVZ)
```

However, I encountered the following error message:

> Error in fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
> negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values

I tried changing from R version 4.3.2 to 4.2.2, yet the problem remains. Can you shed some light on the issue?

My OS is Windows 10 Pro.

I did try changing the R version and reinstalling the packages.

Comment: This is surprising ... a [mcve] would be best, but in the meantime can you show us `summary(tddcVZ[,c("age", "treatment")])` and `with(tddcVZ, table(vial, treatment))` ? i.e., how many observations do you have, how many treatments, how are observations distributed among vials and treatments ... ?

Comment: I also have just started getting this error on some beta distribution models in glmmTMB that were working prior to an update of R and fresh download of the package. Just adding that context.

Comment: I just resolved the error for me, so have posted an answer with instructions how and a very brief explanation of what I suspect is causing the error for you.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a problem relating to the recent changes to the package `Matrix`. See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2023q4/010051.html) for details.

I was encountering the same problems as you with models that were previously working, and when I tried to run them in lme4 I also got some unusual error and failure to run ([this error, also on SO with related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481539/error-in-initializeptr-function-cholmod-factor-ldeta-not-provided-by-pack)).

I was able to resolve the errors for both lme4 and glmmTMB by reinstalling Matrix from the source (v 1.6-2). I suspect that will work for you too.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This solved it for me, too. However, note that I first reinstalled Matrix v 1.6-3 and IT DID NOT WORK. It really only worked after installing v 1.6-2. What irritates me even more is that I now have "Matrix" appear twice in my package list - once as v.16-2 and once as 1.5-4.1. The latter cannot be removed.

Comment: Try `installed.packages() |> as.data.frame() |> subset(Package=="Matrix", select = c(LibPath, Version))` to see where/which versions are installed. You can always go delete those particular directories by hand, through your OS.

Comment: Facing the same issue, I had to reinstall Matrix version 1.6-1.1 for glmmTMB to work.