# "Error in initializePtr() : function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'" when using lmer function in R

Tags: r, lme4

I am attempting to build a mixed effects linear regression model using the lmer function in R. I am building a fixed effects and mixed effects model using the following code to justify the use of a mixed effects model by comparing the AICs. I have tried reloading the lme4 package multiple times and restarting between uploads (as recommended in other questions); however, this has not resolved the error. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

```r
    `# generate models
    m0.glm <- glm(SPL ~ 1, family = Gamma, data = CP)
    m0.lmer = lmer(SPL ~ 1 + (1|Lunar), REML = T, data = CP)

    `# compare models
    AIC(logLik(m0.glm))
    AIC(logLik(m0.lmer))

    > m0.glm <- glm(SPL ~ 1, family = Gamma, data = CP)
    > m0.lmer = lmer(SPL ~ 1 + (1|Lunar), REML = T, data = CP)
```

```
    Error in initializePtr() : 
      function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'`
```

Answer (score 35):

**Matrix** < 1.6-2 and **Matrix** >= 1.6-2 are binary incompatible.  When you change between them, you must re-install *from sources* packages that link **Matrix** and therefore depend on the **Matrix** [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface):

```r
> tools::package_dependencies("Matrix", which = "LinkingTo", reverse = TRUE)[[1L]]
 [1] "ahMLE"               "bayesWatch"          "cplm"               
 [4] "GeneralizedWendland" "hibayes"             "irlba"              
 [7] "lme4"                "mcmcsae"             "OpenMx"             
[10] "PRIMME"              "robustlmm"           "spGARCH"            
[13] "TMB"                 "bcSeq"
```

If you have the required tools [1], then you can re-install **lme4** from sources:

```r
install.packages("lme4", type = "source")
```

If not, then you need to install compatible binaries of **Matrix** and **lme4** from a repository.  Not all repositories provide compatible binaries, but CRAN does [2], so the following should work in most cases:

```r
oo <- options(repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/")
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("lme4")
options(oo)
```

Note that binaries in all repositories will be rebuilt automatically once **lme4** > 1.1-35.1 is released.  At that point, a simple `update.packages()` call will get things working again, even without explicit setting of `repos`.

See also my announcement on the R-package-devel mailing list from November 11: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2023q4/010054.html

---

1. Windows users should install RTools, as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/); macOS users should install the Command Line Tools for Xcode and GNU Fortran, as described [here](https://mac.r-project.org/tools/); Linux users should already have the required tools.
2. For Windows (R 4.2, 4.3, 4.4), macOS x86_64 (R 4.3), and macOS arm64 (R 4.2, 4.3).

Answer (score 8):

I recieved the same error, but using the binary version (1.5-4) of Matrix fixed it.

Edit: My solution to this error was as described below.

Bolker and Jagan have more insightful contributions

```
remove.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("Matrix")
```

Simply click "no" in the pop up about installing from source and compilation.

```
library(matrix)
```

Or alternatively this should work

```
remove.packages("Matrix")
remove.packages("lme4")
install.packages("lme4", type = "source")
library(lme4)
```

Installing lme4 will also include the Matrix package (a binary version).

However you want to go about it, just make sure you're using a binary version of the Matrix packag (1.5-4 being the latest).

Comment: I am **extremely** skeptical that there is a bug in Matrix version 1.6-4.  The problem is (I am >99% sure) that there is a binary *incompatibility* in the stack of binaries from whatever package repository you're using. I would also be surprised if following @MikaelJagan's answer *precisely* didn't resolve the problem.  That said, downgrading the `Matrix` package to a binary version that's compatible with the rest of your packages is definitely *a* solution ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes you are probably correct. I should have read the post and replies more thoroughly before replying. I just remembered running into the same error a few days ago and "solved" it the way I described, and was eager to "help".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error code. Trying to update/reinstall packages using the code above starting with oo<- led to multiple errors and loops asking about restarting R. However closing R and restarting seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Restarting the R session helps me solve the problem.