# error message in running lmer mixed effects model with lme4 package

Tags: r

I am running this model

```
model4 = lmer(weight ~ weeks + (1|person), data = data)
```

where the dependent variable is weight for individuals measured over time period (weeks). I include random intercept/fixed slope for the individuals. I am getting this error message when I run using the lme4 package:

```
Error in initializePtr() : 
  function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'
```

I have tried to close out of R and reinstall lme4 and continue to get the same error. What does this error mean?

Comment: What version of R and `lme4` are you running?

Comment: I am running on R 4.3.1

Answer (score 3):

This error points to a problem with the package 'Matrix', on which the 'lme4' is dependent.
There are different possible reasons for this kind of problem. You may start by updating the package 'Matrix' and reinstalling the 'lme4'. To do this in a new environment, you can run the following code:

```
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("lme4")
```

Then, you can restart your session, open your script and rerun your code. Please pay attention to any warning messages as you load the packages.

If that does not solve your problem, please check for any conflicts among the loaded packages.

If this answer is helpful, please remember to recommend it.

Otherwise, please give us information about the versions of R and the packages you are using. That way, we can provide more specific answers.

Comment: You might note in your answer that this is due to recent updates of `Matrix` and `lme4`. Installing from source (`... type = "source")` might be necessary. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481539/error-in-initializeptr-function-cholmod-factor-ldeta-not-provided-by-pack

Comment: Thanks, installing Matrix and lme4 worked perfectly!