Can't Install "lme4" Package in R (Version 2023.12.1+402)
When I try to run library(lme4), I'm given this output:
library(lme4)
Loading required package: Matrix
Warning message:
In check_dep_version() : ABI version mismatch: 
lme4 was built with Matrix ABI version 1
Current Matrix ABI version is 0
Please re-install lme4 from source or restore original ‘Matrix’ package

I'm not sure what to do in order to get past this.
I tried the normal code for installing packages:
install.packages("lme4")
library(lme4)


Did you try first update the package Matrix, and then install lme4?

What version of R are you running?

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77531357/error-message-in-running-lmer-mixed-effects-model-with-lme4-package , esp the install from source part in the comments.

I suggest you upgrade all installed packages.

This is a case where your Matrix package is too old. The version number you give in the title is an RStudio version number, which isn't useful here. If possible you should update the Matrix package to 1.7.0. However, you can only do this if you're running R version 4.4.
Otherwise, you should reinstall lme4 from source, or from a repository with a consistently built binary Matrix/lme4 stack, as described here.

Ben, do you know how to accomplish this with GitHub Actions? I'm struggling to figure out the right way to sort this out for R 4.3.x (oldrelease); I've tried forcing Matrix and lme4 reinstalls (in all combinations of those two) to no avail.

which OS? My first guess would be to put in a separate Rscript step that runs the code in the linked question, although I'm not sure.  When I was trying to solve a similar problem (archived dotwhisker) I ended up doing the install run for the packages I needed, then using with: extra-packages: any::rcmdcheck, dotwhisker=?ignore in the setup-r-dependencies step to get it to not try to install dotwhisker as usual (see .github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml in the glmmTMB repo)

Thanks Ben; it was on Linux (Ubuntu - R 4.3.x). I seem to have fixed the issue by one or a combination of using lme4=?source in extra-packages to force rebuilding lme4 from source with whatever Matrix was installed, and not using the devel version of pak. I was previously advised to the devel version of pak (when R 4.3.x was r-release), but I think this has since become stable so I should have used that.
