# Error in lmer in RStudio (Error in initializePtr() : function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix')

Tags: r, lme4

I have been using lmer/lme4 for a while with no issues. However, I have been getting this error recently when using two different computers in my lab. It works fine if I use a different computer, and it does not work if a coworker logs into either of the two "bad" computers. All are on the same server and same version of R (4.3.2).

> Error in initializePtr() :
> function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'

I ran the following on both computers, which fixed the issue on one computer but not the other.

```
oo <- options(repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/")
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("lme4")
options(oo)
```

I have no idea why this solution does not work for one of the computers. It also does not work if a coworker logs in on this computer. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481539/error-in-initializeptr-function-cholmod-factor-ldeta-not-provided-by-pack). The issue appears to be incompatible versions of `Matrix` and `lme4`.

Comment: Note that you have to re-install `lme4` **from source** in order for this to work.