# lmer in Matrix package

Tags: r, lme4

I have a problem regarding the lmer and glmer functions. An error appears when I use the functions:

```
Error in initializePtr() : 
  function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'
```

When I use `install.packages(“Matrix”)` a pop-up appears that keeps telling me to restart R but does nothing. I have installed the newest R and Rstudio versions as well as Rtools.
Could anyone help me?

Hereby a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77532685/5221626

Answer (score 2):

`Matrix` seems to be getting reloaded automatically when you restart your R session. It's not immediately obvious how to [start RStudio in '--vanilla' mode](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-do-an-r-vanilla-in-rstudio-console/13601), i.e. making sure that no data/packages other than the base packages get loaded on startup.  ([This mailing list post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2020-October/469132.html) suggests running `startup::startup(debug = TRUE, dryrun = TRUE)` to see what information is being automatically loaded when you restart RStudio.)

You might be able to do this by, e.g., deleting any `.RData` files that are lying around (and moving `.Renviron`/`.Rprofile` files temporarily if you have them), but the easiest way to do this might be to open a terminal window, run `R --vanilla` there (assuming that R is in your path/Windows can find your R executable ...), and run `install.packages("Matrix")` in that session.

(Even if you start a clean session, if you run the code in the order in which it occurs in your displayed file, you'll have problems because you call `library("Matrix")` before `install.packages("Matrix")`.  However, that doesn't seem to be the problem based on your console history displayed.)