# Can't install older versions of Matrix package

Tags: r, bioconductor, seurat, rna-seq

I've been having a series of issues that I tried to track down the origin of the problem and I think it's because I can't install Matrix 1.6-1.
I need to run a `quickCluster` function on a `SingleCellExperiment` object but I have the following error:

> Error in (function (A, nv = 5, nu = nv, maxit = 1000, work = nv + 7, reorth = TRUE,  :
> function 'as_cholmod_sparse' not provided by package 'Matrix'

Looking this error up, I found other people that had the same error and could get around it by installing an older version of Matrix. So I tried this:

```
   install.packages("remotes")
   remotes::install_version("Matrix", version = "1.6-1")
```

And got this:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
> '-L/opt/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.0/12.2.0' ld: warning:
> directory not found for option '-L/opt/gfortran/lib' ld: library not
> found for -lgfortran clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [Matrix.so] Error 1 ERROR:
> compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’
>
> - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/Matrix’
> - restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/Matrix’
>   Warning message: In i.p(...) :   installation of package
>   ‘/var/folders/mx/spt7cbq57gn6ssxwq_yhzmqh0000gp/T//RtmpxuzZmQ/remotes2e406022dae6/Matrix’
>   had non-zero exit status

I have tried removing `Matrix`, removing `irlba`, removing Seurat, installing all over again and nothing works. Thoughts?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] SummarizedExperiment_1.32.0 gtable_0.3.4                beeswarm_0.4.0              ggplot2_3.4.4              
 [5] remotes_2.4.2.1             processx_3.8.3              ggrepel_0.9.5               Biobase_2.62.0             
 [9] lattice_0.22-5              callr_3.7.3                 ps_1.7.6                    vctrs_0.6.5                
[13] tools_4.3.2                 bitops_1.0-7                generics_0.1.3              stats4_4.3.2               
[17] parallel_4.3.2              tibble_3.2.1                fansi_1.0.6                 pkgconfig_2.0.3            
[21] BiocNeighbors_1.20.2        Matrix_1.6-5                S4Vectors_0.40.2            sparseMatrixStats_1.14.0   
[25] lifecycle_1.0.4             GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.11     compiler_4.3.2              munsell_0.5.0              
[29] codetools_0.2-19            vipor_0.4.7                 GenomeInfoDb_1.38.5         RCurl_1.98-1.14            
[33] pillar_1.9.0                crayon_1.5.2                BiocParallel_1.36.0         SingleCellExperiment_1.24.0
[37] DelayedArray_0.28.0         viridis_0.6.5               abind_1.4-5                 tidyselect_1.2.0           
[41] rsvd_1.0.5                  BiocSingular_1.18.0         dplyr_1.1.4                 grid_4.3.2                 
[45] colorspace_2.1-0            cli_3.6.2                   SparseArray_1.2.3           scater_1.30.1              
[49] magrittr_2.0.3              S4Arrays_1.2.0              pkgbuild_1.4.3              utf8_1.2.4                 
[53] DelayedMatrixStats_1.24.0   scales_1.3.0                ggbeeswarm_0.7.2            XVector_0.42.0             
[57] matrixStats_1.2.0           gridExtra_2.3               reticulate_1.34.0           png_0.1-8                  
[61] ScaledMatrix_1.10.0         beachmat_2.18.0             GenomicRanges_1.54.1        IRanges_2.36.0             
[65] viridisLite_0.4.2           irlba_2.3.5.1               rlang_1.1.3                 Rcpp_1.0.12                
[69] glue_1.7.0                  scuttle_1.12.0              BiocGenerics_0.48.1         rstudioapi_0.15.0          
[73] jsonlite_1.8.8              plyr_1.8.9                  R6_2.5.1                    MatrixGenerics_1.14.0      
[77] zlibbioc_1.48.0
```

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings with more detail about the compilation failure? Since you are having trouble, you might try [downloading the source straight from the CRAN archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Matrix/) and installing it from the local file with the `verbose` setting turned on, `install.packages("/path/to/your/downloaded/Matrix", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)`. This may give more clues as to the issue.

Comment: Also, from your session info, we can see you've got over 100 packages attached or loaded. Restart R and try this from a fresh R session before you load any other packages.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) make sure you are installing the old version of `Matrix` in a **clean** R session (in particular, no packages loaded except for `remotes`) (2) if that doesn't work, please edit your question to include more of the error message(s) from the compilation

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I tried installing the old version in a clean session and the same error came up. I have edited the question by adding more information on the error message and changed the session info from what I got trying in a new session.

Comment: I know this is late but what is the output of `BiocManager::valid()`? It should be TRUE. It seems that you might have problem with mixing different versions of packages that were never tested to work together. In any case I recommend to use `BiocManager::install(version = "3.18")` to use the latest version of R with the corresponding versions of Bioconductor and CRAN packages.

Comment: The compilation failed because the linker is not finding an installation of GNU Fortran in the expected location: https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ ... Having said that, it's not clear to me that installing an earlier version of **Matrix** will necessarily solve your problem.  You should look at this recent Q&A, if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77532685/12685768

Comment: Troubleshooting this with a student and seems like the real culprit here is `irlba` which hasn't been able to successfully build on **macos-arm64** platform since July. Since it links against Matrix and Matrix updated it's ABI in 1.6-2, this is what causes the runtime error that starts from `scran::quickCluster`.