# R package glmmTMB - model family nbinom2 - Error in MakeADFunObject

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mixed-models, glmmtmb, glmm

I could use some quick assistance with fitting a negative binomial model in R using the "glmmTMB" package with the family set to nbinom2. I opted for glmmTMB because it allows specifying fixed and random effects in both the main and zero-inflated parts of the formula, and it also supports parallel computing.

```
nt <- parallel::detectCores()-1
neg_bin <- glmmTMB(eq_main, # eq_main has both fixed and random effects, and an offset term in fixed effects
                    data = x,
                    ziformula = eq_zeros, # eq_zeros has only fixed effects; no random effects
                    family = nbinom2,
                    REML = TRUE, control = glmmTMBControl(parallel = nt))
```

However, I've hit a roadblock with the following error:

> "Error in MakeADFunObject(data, parameters, reportenv, ADreport =
> ADreport, : Caught exception 'std::bad_alloc' in function
> 'MakeADFunObject'"

Can someone shed light on what this error means and suggest steps I could take to resolve it? I would like to think that it is not a memory issue because I am utilizing the most state-of-the-art machine I was able to get my hands on (A.K.A. a supercomputer). Thanks in advance for your help!

NOTE: I recognize the importance of sharing a reproducible example, but due to the extensive size of the dataset (comprising several hundred variables), I'm currently refraining from providing one. If the community deems it necessary, I am more than willing to share a reproducible example upon request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "running-out-memory" error.

- it would help a lot if you told us more about the dimensions of your problem: how many observations total? How many variables, and in particular how many factor variables with how many levels? In particular, what is

```r
dim(model.matrix(lme4::nobars(eq_main), data = x))
```

(and the equivalent for your zero-inflation model formula)?

- "most state-of-the-art machine I was able to get my hands on" is actually not very descriptive; how much RAM is available? (If you are running this in a high-performance-computing (HPC) facility, how much memory have you requested for the job?)
- can you try running some examples with small subsets of your data (subsetting predictor variables, observations, or both), and see (1) how big a subset you can successfully run and (2) how the memory requirements and computing time scale with problem size? (The `peakRAM` package is useful for this — it will report elapsed time, memory usage, and peak memory usage.)

- I would be surprised if parallelizing is affecting your memory usage (`glmmTMB` uses OpenMP, which is a shared-memory approach), but it couldn't hurt to try without parallelizing to see if it makes a difference.

The only suggestion I can make off the top of my head/without further information that *might* help is to try `sparseX = TRUE` in your `glmmTMB()` call: *if* you have a lot of factor variables with many levels, which will get expanded into many columns containing mostly zeros, this could reduce the memory footprint of your problem.

Comment: Comment cut off?  If that call makes you run out of memory too, then try `library("Matrix"); X <- sparse.model.matrix(lme4::nobars(eq_main), data = x); dim(X); object.size(X)`

Comment: Thank you for your insights, Ben Bolker! When I ran the code – dim(model.matrix(lme4::nobars(eq_main), data = x)) – the results were 2506967, 68 for the main formula and 2506967, 8 for the zero-inflated formula. I'm dealing with three significant factor variables, each with numerous levels (50, 2000+, 15000+). On the HPC, I used 1 node, 48 cores, and 192 GB memory, which is the max I could request. I will test the model on a data subset and explore your other suggestions. I welcome if you have any further tips or suggestions for me.

Comment: Not sure how you can have "hundreds of variables" but only 68 columns in your model matrix ... ??  If the factor variables are being modeled as *fixed effects* you should definitely try `sparseX = TRUE`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of running the model with data subsets but got a different error "negative log-likelihood is NaN at starting parameter values."
I found two SO posts that discuss this:
install Matrix package v1.6-2
(suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77466641/error-in-fittmbtmbstruc-negative-log-likelihood-is-nan-at-starting-parameter)
add argument start = list(psi = c(-1,1))
(suggested in https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/883)
Both have not worked for me. I am wondering if the fix mentioned in the previous post could help in my situation. Thanks